# the associated property circle in the .m/.h file how to enter to the associated control in the xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just want to display associated storyboard or xib's control through clicking filled circle on the left of property in the class .m or .h file.however,I click the circle ,the system recognize to add  a breakpoint in current line.It dose not work like that I want.what should I change some setting about xcode ?
the picture description below：

[image]

Comment: I've never used it a lot (only a couple times), but you ma have to maintained Alt, CmD and/or Shift to see it.

Comment: Thanks ,I have tried many methods ,but not success.I don't know whether it relates the updated Xcode which changed inner.